# Why is this Javascript/HTML5 Canvas not working?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, html5-canvas

I am trying to create a simple game and on pressing the right and left buttons a picture is supposed to move (and vary between another picture, `trexf` and `trexb`).

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480" >
    Browser doesn't support canvas.
</canvas>
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var width, height, rightKey = false, leftKey = false, upKey = false, downKey = false, rex_x, rex_y = 300, trexf, trexb;

trexf = new Image('Trexf.png');
trexb = new Image('Trexb.png');

function clearCanvas() {
    canvas.width = canvas.width;
}

function drawRex() {
    if(rightKey) {
        rex_x += 5;
    } else if(leftKey) {
        rex_x -= 5;
    }

    ctx.drawImage(trexf, rex_x, rex_y);
    if(rightKey == false || leftKey == false) {
        ctx.drawImage(trexb, rex_x, rex_y);
    }
}

function loop() {
    clearCanvas();
    drawRex();
}

function keyDown(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 39)
        rightKey = true;
    else if(e.keyCode == 37)
        leftKey = true;
}

function keyUp(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 39)
        rightKey = false;
    else if(e.keyCode == 37)
        leftKey = false;
}

function init() {

    ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 30;
    ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 30;

    document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown, false);
    document.addEventListener('keyup', keyUp, false);

    rex_x = canvas.width / 2;

    setInterval(loop, 1000);
}

init();
```

**[Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/bTvBn/) on JSFiddle.**

Why does this not work as I expect?

Comment: By 'does not work as I expect', please let us know exactly how it's not working, *and* how you expect it to work. If we don't know the issue, we can't solve it :)

Comment: Nothing is showing up. I explained how it was supposed to work but nothing is even happening. I get an error for an uncaught exception location JS Frame

Comment: What's the uncaught exception say?

Comment: [21:47:49.346] uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) [nsIDOMCanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage]"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: file:///C:/Users/hassooni/Documents/Vis40/AR15.html :: drawRex :: line 68"  data: no]

Comment: also this error?! [21:54:22.348] Use of getAttributeNodeNS() is deprecated. Use getAttributeNS() instead. @ file:///C:/Users/hassooni/Documents/Vis40/AR15.html

Comment: The jsFiddle seems to work for me, if you hold down the left or right arrow key for over a second the images start moving, which is exactly what you'd expect to happen from reading the code.

Comment: works for me in chrome, try a modern browser

Comment: Works for me in Chrome as @Christian Varga said. Why don't you try to redraw the scene in a moveLeft/moveRight method called by the event emitter instead of using a using a loop? Should smooth things out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me in Chrome, but your draw interval is too large (1 second) so the key up event is firing before the redraw.

Answer (score 0):

dial down your interval timer delay count:

http://jsfiddle.net/bTvBn/42/

It works fine now.